# Menu items are loading the same command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def generate_menu(self):
    self.some_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Some Label", menu=self.some_menu)

    some_directory = SCRIPT_ROOT + "/" + SOME_FOLDER

    for filename in os.listdir(some_directory):
        test_file = (test_directory + "/" + filename)
        print(test_file)
        self.some_menu.add_command(label=filename, command=lambda: self.files.add_files(test_file))
```

This code generates a menu item with a dropdown containing:

- File 1
- File 2
- File 3

and so on.

Each file option should have an individual command calling the same function but with a different argument.

```
self.files.add_files(<argument should be based on iteration of for loop)
```

What is happening is that each file option is actually using the command for File 3 (or the last file on the dropdown).

There is a fault in logic somewhere - can you spot it?

Comment: You are relying on closures; these are dereferenced when the function is *called*, not when it is defined. As such, the `test_file` name has moved on from when you printed it and now points to the last generated name. The solution is to not rely on a closure, see the duplicate.

Comment: For example, `command=partial(self.files.add_files, test_file)` would work, as the `test_file` reference is captured in the `functools.partial()` object.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked - thanks for the super fast reply and sorry for the duplicate!